# Реализация дерева вопросов

Tags: алгоритм, структуры, любой-язык, дерево

Я хочу в приложении сделать что то наподобие окошка, с тремя кнопками
Где в окно выводится вопрос, а методом нажатия кнопок "да", "нет", или "назад"(если неверно ответил) ты приходишь к конкретному ответу, и выполняются какие то действия. 
Как можно реализовать подобное? 
- Был вариант использовать класс с ссылкой на родительский объект, и два дочерних (как бы варианты ответа) 
Но здесь возникла проблема в инициализации самой иерархии, как задавать дочерние компоненты если их еще нет, и как вообще построить дерево не используя куча сеттеров и вручную создаваемых объектов с инициализацией каждого поля. 
- Был вариант использовать xml но здесь куча сложностей с обходом вложенных тегов. Только проблемы и головная боль. Туторов и мануалов нигде нет подходящих, в доках ничего полезного не нашел ну или не заметил. (хотя действительно пытался) 
- Есть вариант написать дерево на html и просто парсить по типу: взять дочерние элементы, вытянуть вопрос, если нажата кнопка "да" взять первый дочерний элемент, если "нет" то второй. Если назад то вернуть родительский элемент. Но подключать для этого jsoup да и вообще парсинг как то слишком для этого.
Подскажите как можно реализовать такую штуку, если не другим способом, то хотя бы адекватно одним из вышеописанных. Уже второй день стоит эта проблема.

Comment: Я такое делал для пары квестов. Создаете файл json или xml, как удобней, при загрузке программы подгружаете его и создаете базу с ответами. Каждый вопрос - это объект класса Вопрос, в котором есть сам вопрос, набор ответов и индекс правильного ответа.

Comment: @MichaelVaysman проблема то в том, что до этого я додумался, а вот грамотно реализовать, не знаю как. с xml куча проблем в плане узлов, нельзя просто так взять и получить дочерние узлы и брать из них информацию. Мне хотя бы пример малейший, как это делается, на ютубе и в гугле практически нет инфы о том как парсить подобные структуры и тем более создавать на их основе иерархию объектов

Comment: А, понял. Набросаю вам через часок... А вам на каком языке надо? C# нормально?

Comment: [пример динамического меню для выбора настроек игры, написанном в continuation passing style (CPS) на Питоне](https://ideone.com/I3T3wq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код написан на C#.
Значит так, сначала структура файла:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<questions>
    <question text="What time is it?">
        <answers>
            <answer text="12:34" />
            <answer text="08:42" />
            <answer correct='true' text="11:42" />
        </answers>
    </question>
    <question text="Quantity of cantimeters in one meter?">
        <answers>
            <answer text="95" />
            <answer correct="true" text="100" />
            <answer text="1000" />
        </answers>
    </question>
    <question text="Quontity of minutes in one hour?">
        <answers>
            <answer correct="true" text="60" />
            <answer text="3600" />
            <answer text="100" />
        </answers>
    </question>
</questions>
```

Теперь код парсера (выглядит все просто, но если есть какие-то вопросы по коду с удовольствием отвечу. Так же можно все написать по другому, но это то что я собрал на коленке ):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace xmlTester
{
    class Question
    {
        public string Text { get; set;}
        public List<string> Answers;
        public int CorrectAnswerIndex { get; set; }
        public Question()
        {
            Text = "";
            Answers = new List<string>();
            CorrectAnswerIndex = -1;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string str = "";

            if(Text != "" && Answers.Count > 0 && CorrectAnswerIndex != -1) //if everything is ok
            {
                str += "Question: " + Text + "\r\n";
                str += "Possible answers:\r\n";
                foreach(string answer in Answers)
                {
                    str += "- " + answer + "\r\n";
                }
                str += "The correct answer is: " + Answers[CorrectAnswerIndex] + "\r\n";
            }

            return str;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        static List<Question> questionsList = new List<Question>();

        static void LoadQuestions()
        {
            try
            {
                xmlDoc.Load(@"D:\Users\desk\Documents\test.xml");
                XmlNode questions = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/questions"); //root node name, should be with slash '/'!
                if (questions.HasChildNodes)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode question in questions.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        Question q = new Question();
                        string text = question.Attributes["text"]?.InnerText;
                        q.Text = (text == null) ? "" : text; //if text is null, return empty string

                        if (question.HasChildNodes) //we must be sure, that it's valid question structure
                        {
                            XmlNode answers = question.FirstChild;
                            if(answers.HasChildNodes) //answers should have a child nodes
                            {
                                foreach(XmlNode answer in answers.ChildNodes)
                                {
                                    string answerText = answer.Attributes["text"]?.InnerText;
                                    string isCorrect = answer.Attributes["correct"]?.InnerText;

                                    q.Answers.Add((answerText == null) ? "" : answerText); //if anserText is null, return ampty string
                                    if(isCorrect != null && isCorrect == "true")
                                    {
                                        q.CorrectAnswerIndex = q.Answers.Count - 1; //index is quantity of the answers minus 1.
                                    }
                                } //end of foreach(XmlNode answer in answers.ChildNodes)
                            } //end of if(answers.HasChildNodes)
                        } //end of if (question.HasChildNodes)

                        questionsList.Add(q);
                    } //end of foreach (XmlNode question in questions.ChildNodes)
                } //end of if (questions.HasChildNodes)
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoadQuestions();

            foreach (Question q in questionsList) //if questionsList is empty, the program is not enters to the loop at all
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                Console.Write(q.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------\n");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Надеюсь мой ответ вам помежет разобраться :)